# how to manage collisions with opengl

Tags: collision

I am using those forms,

first one :

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0,5,17);
glScalef(1,0.5,1);
glutSolidCube(1.5);
glPopMatrix();
```

Second one :

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, -11, 5);
glutSolidSphere(0.6, 100, 100);
glPopMatrix();
```

And I need to manage collisions.

Could you tell me how I could proceed to create a kind of alert, or to detect when those two forms collide with each other ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use physic engine, opengl is not a suitable tool.  It is usually the time to learn some more libraries.

Comment: I have to use opengl, I have no choice.

Comment: Why can't you use other libraries?  Do someones forbid you to do so?

Comment: You are talking about a library which I put into my opengl code ?

Comment: Do you know [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/)?  It is totally free.  You will not put it **into** opengl code.  It doesn't care about Opengl's transformation.

Comment: I don't know how tu use Bullet and have no time to learn. I just need to create a function in my code which will make sure a form will be removed when another form is close to it.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  This might be closest to what you want.  http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html   I took sometimes, but not much as Bullet.   It would be nice to know if it is useful for you.